How to avoit jitter in the call frequency of listen() in the Dart stream subsciption?
I'm using a ZMQ library in my Dart/Flutter project for the network communication. I have a pair of PUB/SUB TCP sockets and the publisher pushes one message every 100ms. I use this code for listening to the messages on the receiving side:
m_frameDataSubscripiton = m_subscribeSocket.messages.listen((msg) async {
    Iterator<ZFrame> it = msg.iterator;
    if (it.moveNext()) {
      while (it.current.hasMore) {
        it.moveNext();
      }
      if (it.current.payload.isNotEmpty) {
        print("Got the frame packet at " + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + " size " + it.current.payload.length.toString());
      }
    }
  },
  onError: (Object error) {
    m_status = "subscription error";
    notifyListeners();
  },
  onDone: () {
    m_status = "done";
    notifyListeners();
  });

The messages are received just fine however I noticed something strange with the time distribution of them. It seems like calls to listen(msg) are "packed" into bursts with 1-2ms between calls and then there is a pause of 1000ms. Here is the table of the received timestamps that better illustrates the situation:

I tried different strategies to make the receiving times more uniform, including setting the lower high watermark of the receiving socket, but that raises exception for all values lower than default(1000). I also tried using RxDart package and use the timed buffer in the stream with (100ms) polling time but it resulted in subscription still being polled every 1000ms still with the rest of the messages being simply dropped.
Is there any way to force the subscription to flush its buffer every time a single message is received?

this is how the stream data is produced by ZMQ, it has nothing to do with stream subscription, for example try: `void main() {
generator().listen((i) {
print('$i ${DateTime.now().millisecond}');
});
}
Stream generator() async* {
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
yield i;
}
}- theprintis called every ~10ms becausegenerator()` produces new data every 10ms - they are not "buffered"

I suspected that the buffering might happen in the ZMQ itself. That is why I tried lowering the HWM of the receiving socket (its done by setting the ZMQ_RCVHWM socket option). But that doesn't seem to work for any value lower than 1000.

Turns out the reason was in the hard-coded polling duration inside the dart ZMQ lib: https://github.com/enwi/dartzmq/issues/4
